# What effects does a change in IV on the call side have on the put side?

Tags: options, trading, stock-markets, call-options, black-scholes

In a European type options market, consider this scenario, where someone starts to **buy call** options very aggressively which **increases call IV** rapidly. At the same time, the underlying price remains the same.
What impact this increase in IV on the call side will have on the **put side IV** of the same strike price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To a good approximation, [IV is always the same for European puts and calls](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/7604/does-implied-vol-vary-for-calls-vs-puts) of the same strike and expiration, because of [put-call parity](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/putcallparity.asp). So put IV will rise along with call IV. This relationship holds no matter what happens to the underlying price.

There may be a misconception in your question, that the underlying price would reasonably remain constant when "someone starts to buy call options very aggressively". Rather, this would be expected to push upward not only IV but also the underlying price. See [this comment](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/100609/does-option-demand-influence-option-price#comment184428_100611):

> But if there is demand specifically for, say, calls to make a bullish bet, then as the calls rise, other traders will arbitrage by selling them and going long the underlying; i.e., the bullish demand gets communicated to the underlying. Puts may then fall as a result.